# Issue is with Route Name

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

Why when I kill project it show click text but when I refresh it  write in center page rote not defined mean switch case statement is default. It repeat all time WHY??
Can anyone please solve my issue

```
class Routes{
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
    switch(settings.name){
      case RoutesName.home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>home_screen());

      case RoutesName.login:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>login());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: Text("No Rote defined"),),
          );
        });
    }
  }
}
```

```
   class RoutesName{
  ///account routes name
  static const String login="login";
  ///home-screen routes name
  static const String home="home_screen";

}
```

```
  return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            utils.flushBarErrorMessage("No internet connection", context);

          },
          child: Text("Click"))),
    );
```

```
return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
    home: login(),
      onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialRoute`

is Missing in your `MaterialApp`, This might be the reason for your App bugging. Although, Here is my personal Code to reference from,

```
    class Routes {
  static MaterialPageRoute generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case RoutesName.homeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomeView(),
        );
      case RoutesName.loginScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginView(),
        );
        
      case RoutesName.splashScren:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const SplashView(),
        );
      case RoutesName.signupScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SignUp(),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No Routes Defined!'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}

 child: const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        initialRoute: RoutesName.splashScren,
        onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
      ),
```